# Google Chrome - Is it possible to have a button to open the Developer Tools

Tags: google-chrome

So I am trying o make the switch from Firefox to Chrome and one big hurdle for me is moving from Firebug to Chrome's developer tools.  The developer tools works fine, I'd just like to have a button on the screen to click to access them as opposed to a menu option (I know there's a shortcut keystroke but I can't remember half of the ones I need as it is)

Is there a way to add a button or a bookmark in the bookmarks bar that would open the developer tools panel?

I'm running the latest version on OS X 10.7.

---

**A little more detail**

In OS X 10.7 
<kbd>F12</kbd> opens dashboard while <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> increases the volume

That functionality can be changed so that <kbd>F12</kbd> increases the volume and <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> opens the dashboard via System Preferences.

Comment: I know you said you don't want to remember keycodes, but F12 is used by default in both Firefox (for firebug) and chrome (on the PC). Could you not just remember that one? :P

Comment: F12 opens my dashboard, (A Mac thing)... :-(

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you're happy with simply pressing a key, then you can have <kbd>F12</kbd> work like so (instructions tested on OSX 10.8):

- Open `Keyboard Shortcuts` Preferences
- Click "Mission Control" from the list
- Untick "Show Dashboard" (disable default beahviour of <kbd>F12</kbd>)
- Click "Application Shortcuts" from the list
- Click the "+" below the right-hand list
- Select Google Chrome from the drop down list
- In "Menu Title", type `Developer Tools`
- Click in "Keyboard Shortcut", then press <kbd>F12</kbd>

Open Chrome, and press <kbd>F12</kbd> - Dev Tools should open right up!

---

[image: F12 to open Chrome Dev Tools]

**I have set <kbd>F12</kbd> to open Dev Tools, and <kbd>F5</kbd> to Refresh the page**

Comment: Oh, perfect.  I added "Firebug" Under Firefox as well to keep life sane - any chance you know what would bring up the Inspector in Firefox?  "Inspector" & Toggle Tools" don't seem to work.

Comment: I'm afraid not - it looks like FF might be doing something magic with the menu options that 'Application Shortcuts' can't handle. _However_, if you [install Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/), then you setup the shortcut for `Firebug` to map to `F12`, which works :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Fn-F12 will do the trick? (IIRC, you can switch between the default behavior of F-keys in your system settings). Otherwise, it's `⌥⌘I` or `⌥⌘J` (the latter opens the console by default.) There is a [good doc](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/WebInspector) about the Web Inspector/DevTools shortcuts.

That said, Google Chrome's design is explicitly minimalistic to avoid UI clutter and reduce the chance of the user getting confused by the things they actually never use, so there is no way to invoke DevTools using a UI button.

Comment: Good thought - Fn-F12 increases the volume :-( - that is the 'other' function of the F12 key in OS X 10.7