# Google signup page: Selenium cannot find select listbox

Tags: selenium, listbox, html

I would like to use selenium to select a value in the `Month` list box for birthday on google page: https://accounts.google.com/SignUp

When I view page code, the code for the list box looks like:

```
<select id="BirthMonth" name="BirthMonth">
 <option value="">Month</option>
 <option value="01" >January</option>
 <option value="02" >February</option>
   ......
 <option value="12" >December</option>
</select>
```

However, when I use Selenium `driver.findElements()`, I cannot find this `select` and its `option` elements. It looks like every list box on this page (as well as `gender` one) cannot be accessed.

Can anyone give some suggestion how Selenium can access to these elements? Thanks

The code is as follows:

```
driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/SignUp");
List<WebElement> inputElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//select[@name]"));

for(WebElement input: inputElements){
    if(input.getTagName().equals("select")){
        Select selectinput = new Select(input);
        List<WebElement> selects = selectinput.getOptions();                            
    }
}
```

I did not get the `select` element I want.

EDIT:

I also try to use `Select select1 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.tagName("select")))` but still cannot find this `BirthMonth` list box. It is wired. There is only one listbox which is inside Javascritpt that can be accessed.

Comment: Show us the code you are using and the full error you are getting

Comment: @Eve ==> FYI : That is not select tag to use Select class in WebDriver.

Comment: @Santoshsarma Can I locate the select element by using findElement(By.xpath), then change it to the Select? Like the way in the code? Thanks

Comment: If the form in question is populated by AJAX, you might need to wait for that to finish. Other than that, `//select[@name]` will match every select element that has a `name` attribute. Do you want `//select[@name='BirthMonth']` instead? Or, to inspect its child elements, `//select[@name='BirthMonth']/option`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a suggestion for how  **access these elements in Selenium**, with a Java example.

It gets a little messy with [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) (which I generally prefer) because this month field has some fancy widgets on it to help hide your choices for security reasons. So here we go with XPath as our selector mechanism.

*Take notice I broke it down - 1st by selecting the month, and 2nd by selecting the month itself. Hope that helps.*

```java
    public class Google Month Example {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            // Just picked Firefox for this example
            FirefoxDriver driver;
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(7, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            // Head to URL
            driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/SignUp");
            // Get the first click on the month field to generate the listbox pop-up
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='BirthMonth']/div")).click();
            // This is ":a" because each item in this month list is assigned a hex value starting at an index of zero
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id=':a']/div")).click();



            // Check to see if November got selected
            if (!driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='BirthMonth']/div[1]")).getText().equals("November")) {
                driver.close();
                throw new RuntimeException("assertText 'November' failed");
            }
            // Close browser window
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
```

**Update: I realized you wanted to pass in the `Month` as an argument.**

So swap out from the example above:

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id=':a']/div")).click();
```

for the below code:

```java
String month = "November";
driver.findElement(By
  .xpath("//div[@class='goog-menuitem']/div[.='" + month + "']")).click();
```

**Second Update:**

So at one point you saw the HTML as:

```xml
<select id="BirthMonth" name="BirthMonth">
 <option value="">Month</option>
 <option value="01" >January</option>
 <option value="02" >February</option>
   ......
 <option value="12" >December</option>
</select>
```

But as I look at it in Chrome Dev Tools right now (pressing F12) after clicking on the  `Month` field I see multiple small structure changes (posted what I see in the  of the [Gist link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7680979)).Examples include  `select` now becoming `span` and `value="01"` now shown as `id=":0"` ([Why the counting starts at zero and not 1](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/110804/why-are-zero-based-arrays-the-norm)). Hope that explains some of why my example is different.

Comment: Thanks Eric. But what does ':a' mean and why did you use `div` instead of 'option' or something else?

Comment: And for xpath: ".//*[@id='BirthMonth'] /div", why need to add "/div"? Because it does not work when the xpath just ".//*[@id='BirthMonth']". @Eric D. Johnson

Comment: Hi Eve, so Google decided to give unique ID tags to the months in the little pop-up (the pretend drop down menu) of *0 = Jan, 1 = Feb*, ... but in [*hex*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal), so instead of 10 = Nov, they used *a = Nov, b = Dec*.

Comment: Also, it's /div instead of option (which is normally used in a drop down) because this is a little piece of custom HTML that Google Wrote. In IE and Chrome, if you hit [*F12*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385140/google-chrome-is-it-possible-to-have-a-button-to-open-the-developer-tools), you can see the HTML. So you can check it out like I did, and see `<span id="BirthMonth"> <div class="goog-inline-block ...</div>`

Comment: Thanks very much Eric. I got it. It is amazing to find that Google uses such class to hide the listbox and the html only be shown when the listbox is clicked. Thanks again! @Eric D. Johnson